# Search multiple keywords in a sentence that are not in the right order as in the search pattern

Tags: gvim

I often need to find several keywords in a sentence.

For example:
This is just a sentence of word1 word3 word4 word2 text in my huge [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) data file.

I can't remember the exact pattern of search, hence I need a search that can do that:

Is there way or plugin that enable search of multiple keywords that are *not* in correct order in a sentence?

For example: I am searching for these keywords (/word1,word2, word3, word4) in a sentence, but in actual fact the order was not like what I thought it was.

Comment: You could take a look at [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#as-vim-plugin) and it's [associated plugin](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) - the `:Lines` or `:BLines` command would do what you're asking.

Comment: I donno if fzf is order-insensitive. I'd simply do `:grep ''\bword1\b|\word2\b'` (with ripgrep as `:h grepprg`). This will return lines where either or both of these words are present. I'd then do a `v:word1:d` and `v:word2:d` in the quickfixlist, which will get rid of the lines where both the words aren't present. And if this were to be a regular operation, I'd write a vimscript function to automate the steps. Lemme know if it helps or if you want me to write the function. I don't wanna work in vain otherwise.

Comment: I can confirm that fzf is order-insensitive.

Comment: @mattb How to install fzf in vim ? I have fzf installed in manjaro ( /usr/bin/fzf /usr/share/fzf  ), but i can't seems to figure out how to install fzf for vim. the Instruction seems to be Very complicated. After reading , make me dizzy
https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/README-VIM.md

Comment: @andrew_ysk that should be posted as a separate question so that people can google and find it in the future (I'd be happy to post an answer!)

Comment: I will be gladly to do so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A little known plugin that comes with Vim distributed is the [LogiPat](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/plugin/logiPat.vim) plugin.

This plugin is distributed with Vim by default and should also be active by default.

In your case I would try to use the following command:

```
LogiPat "word1" & "word2" & "word3" & "word4"
```

which will create the following search pattern: `\%(.*word1.*\&\%(.*word2.*\&\%(.*word3.*\&.*word4.*\)\)\)` and directly search for it. Use `:set hls` to see the effect directly by highlighting all matching positions in your window.

This uses the so called *branch* atom (which you can read about in more detail at [:h /branch](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2Fbranch)), which basically matches for any order of any of the provided arguments in the same line.

It's a bit of a nasty pattern, but the LogiPat plugin makes it a bit easier to use.

Please check the help ([:h logiPat](https://vimhelp.org/pi_logipat.txt.html#logiPat)) for how to use it.

Comment: For reference: logPat is not available by default on Neovim.

Comment: you can still install logipat if you do not have it, even in Neovim :)

Comment: It is still a mystery why this and other runtime plugins were removed from neovim.